# Changing an image on a custom side menu bar

Tags: react-native

I have worked through an example on creating a sidemenu bar in react native:

https://aboutreact.com/custom-navigation-drawer-sidebar-with-image-and-icon-in-menu-options/

Can I replace the image that is located at:

```
'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/'
```

I have tried uploading a .png to flikr but when I save the file, the image is disappearing and not loading the one that I have linked to. Code taken from:

```
const CustomSidebarMenu = (props) => {
  const BASE_PATH =
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/';
  const proileImage = 'react_logo.png';

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      {/*Top Large Image */}
      <Image
        source={{uri: BASE_PATH + proileImage}}
        style={styles.sideMenuProfileIcon}
      />
      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        <DrawerItemList {...props} />
        <DrawerItem
          label="Visit Us"
          onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://aboutreact.com/')}
        />
        <View style={styles.customItem}>
          <Text
            onPress={() => {
              Linking.openURL('https://aboutreact.com/');
            }}>
            Rate Us
          </Text>
          <Image
            source={{uri: BASE_PATH + 'star_filled.png'}}
            style={styles.iconStyle}
          />
        </View>
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
      <Text
        style={{
          fontSize: 16,
          textAlign: 'center',
          color: 'grey'
        }}>
        www.aboutreact.com
      </Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand your problem but you could try to use local images for that. You could save the .png images in a folder called assets and then just use them like this:

```js
import ReactLogo from './assets/react_logo.png';
import StarFilled from  './assets/star_filled.png';

const CustomSidebarMenu = (props) => {

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      {/*Top Large Image */}
      <Image
        source={ReactLogo}
        style={styles.sideMenuProfileIcon}
      />
      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        <DrawerItemList {...props} />
        <DrawerItem
          label="Visit Us"
          onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://aboutreact.com/')}
        />
        <View style={styles.customItem}>
          <Text
            onPress={() => {
              Linking.openURL('https://aboutreact.com/');
            }}>
            Rate Us
          </Text>
          <Image
            source={StarFilled}
            style={styles.iconStyle}
          />
        </View>
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
      <Text
        style={{
          fontSize: 16,
          textAlign: 'center',
          color: 'grey'
        }}>
        www.aboutreact.com
      </Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```